# Scroll multiple TextViews simultaneously

Tags: android, scroll, textview, text-files

I have a string from a file that am storing into 3 separate TextViews because I was having alignments issues with a single TextView.  How can I scroll only this section of my screen to see all of the contents of the file?

```
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
while((line = buf.readLine())!= null) {

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);

    a = st.nextToken();
    b = st.nextToken();
    c = st.nextToken();

    text1.append(a + '\n');
    text2.append(b + '\n');
    text3.append(c + '\n');
}

dp1.setText(text1);
dp2.setText(text2);
dp3.setText(text3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following xml with a few tweaks if needed,

```
<HorizontalScrollView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView  android:id="@+id/dp1"... />
  <TextView  android:id="@+id/dp2"... />
  <TextView  android:id="@+id/dp3"... /> 
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And now in your java code, you can access them as,

```
TextView textV1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dp1);
TextView textV2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dp2);
TextView textV3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dp3);

textV1.setText(text1);
textV2.setText(text2);
textV3.setText(text3);
```

if you want you can use vertical scroll bars as,

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
    android:layout_height="set the height here" >

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried this and it does not seem to work.  It scrolls the fixed area in the screen but not the actual lists located within the TextViews

Comment: there has been some problem with the way u placed SrollView. I have tried it n its properly working. Inspect ur code once...:)

Comment: It is not possible to assign more than one child to `HorizontalScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can place your TextViews inside a HorizontalScrollView in your XML file, like this

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView ... />
    <TextView ... />
    <TextView ... />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: It is not possible to assign more than one child to `HorizontalScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

set `android:ellipsize="marquee"` for your [textViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) in layout file and `setSelected(true)` in your code where your are setting text. I Hope this will help you.