# Scrolling 2 textview in same time with Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I wouldlike to scroll 2 textview in same time:

Code :

```
TextView text_A;
TextView text_B;

A=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
B=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t2);

A.setMouvementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
B.setMouvementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

How can I change this code for works ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put all your text views into a LinearLayout and then put that layout into the ScrollView.For example,

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:scrollbars="horizontal" android:id="@+id/ScrollView">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"                      
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <TextView android:text="@string/textView1" 
        android:id="@+id/t1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

    <TextView android:text="@string/textView2"
        android:id="@+id/t2" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Also try with this link also,
[Try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113738/scroll-multiple-textviews-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

Clean Solution but it requires Api level 23.

```
 textView1.setOnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->

                textView2.scrollX=scrollX
                textView2.scrollY=scrollY
            }
```